# Why doesn't LEGO bring back old series as they were "in the day"

Tags: sets, history, theme

As many of you probably can tell, LEGO has been rehashing old series and giving them a new twist (eg. Rock Raiders -> Power Miners, or whatever its called). Why doesn't LEGO actually make some of those old sets again, without modification (or very little)?

The sheer amount of nostalgia that would come from that would be insane.

Comment: There are a number of reasons I'm sure, however looking at some of the "new versions" of some sets, often there are changes in building techniques (through the addition of new elements for example) which allow for either more accurate shapes or more structurally sound models. Also, while there might be some nostalgia in being able to buy the original yellow castle, I'd much rather have the new articulated horses that are coming with LotR than the original ones made from bricks ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, LEGO **did** at some point reissue some sets (the "legends" series), but then stopped doing so, and it's likely they found out it was not really that interesting to do.

The reasons why would be pure speculation, but at the very least building techniques and available parts do evolve in a way that older sets wouldn't be able to compete with recent ones. As Zhaph mentionned, horses are a very good example.

Also, don't forget that LEGO is producing toys and that kids are their main target audience. Ask a kid what's cooler, the new [Kingdoms Joust](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10223-1) or the yellow castle? Or even any [cool castle set](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10000-1) of the eighties? Why do all minifigs have the same stupid fixed smile? Why don't they have alternate faces on the back of their heads? Where are the animals? Granted, it's a bit of an exageration, but still.

They do take adults into account now, yes, but the "sheer amount of nostalgia" generated by re-issuing older sets may not be that big a market as we would believe. Even adults tend to be more in awe at newer sets (modular houses). I did buy the [re-issue of the USS Constellation](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10021-1), and to be honest... I find nostalgia to be a bit overrated.

Then there's the whole problem of parts which are simply not in production any longer, and for which the cost of reproducing them would offset the potential benefits of reissuing sets. (In other words, don't expect monorails to be reissued ever).

Comment: This said, they also use some "old" parts in new sets. And I allways get a "nostalgic kick" when I see some old parts re-introduced in new sets.

Comment: Hey, ask an adult which is cooler the new Joust or the Yellow Castle and I'd have to say that I really want the Joust - but that might be because I've still got all the bits for the Yellow Castle in my collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess maybe I just get to sobby with nostalgia compared to the rest of their market xD

Comment: No problem, we'll just send yellow bricks your way, and you send us Jousts in return.